# ul list items with different background sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the footer for my website. It's supposed to contain 5 lines of contact information, white text on a black background and white space between. So essentially it will look like 5 black strips on top of each other with white text on them.

The problem is that all the black strips turn out the same length, when I want them to be roughly the length of the text. I tried floating the list items instead of the `<ul>` and put line breaks after each one. The backgrounds were now the right size but I was unable to add the white space between them without messing it up.

HTML:

```
<ul>
                <li>Company name</li>
                <li>Adressadress 123444</li>
                <li>023311 postal code</li>
                <li>+358 12385495955</li>
                <li>info@company.com</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {float:left;
li {
    list-style:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your css and your html?

Comment: Can you post your code in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Adding span tags around the text should solve your problem.

```
<ul>
    <li><span>one</span></li>
    <li><span>two</span></li>
    <li><span>three</span></li>
    <li><span>four</span></li>
    <li><span>five</span></li>
</ul>​


ul {
    margin:10px;
}

ul li {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

ul li span {
    background:black;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwPcv/